# Do events fire/evaluate even if not being called directly?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Here's the scenario:
Let's say I've got a TextBlock, and I slap a `Loaded` event onto it, and in that event, I instruct it to make its `Foreground` orange.

***So it loads, fires the `Loaded` event***, goes to my code and carries out the foreground instruction.

And if I had this TextBlock on 1,000 ListBox items, it would fire this 1,000 times, right?

But if I don't call "Loaded" at all (leaving the textblock as-is), does it still fire the Loaded event in the background 1,000 times in this ListBox scenario?

Comment: Event is not really "fired" if there are no subscribers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And if I had this TextBlock on 1,000 ListBox items, it would fire this 1,000 times, right?

Yes, it would fire as each `TextBlock` gets loaded. Note however that not all 1,000 `TextBlocks` are loaded upfront if the `ListBox` uses UI virtualization (which it does by default).

> But if I don't call "Loaded" at all (leaving the textblock as-is), does it still fire the Loaded event in the background 1,000 times in this ListBox scenario?

The `Loaded` event itself may still be fired for each `TextBlock` that gets loaded into the visual tree provided that there are any other subscribers, but since you are not handling the event you won't really notice.